# Two disks MDADM RAID 1 setup running with one disk

Tags: hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have MDADM RAID 1 with two disks but one failed and will be replaced soon but till this time is it possible to set the raid to active to access my files because now the state is inactive ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You should be able to mount and use degraded raid1. What does "cat /proc/mdstat" show?

Comment: This is the output:

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sda[0](S)
      976630488 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>